# setFormatter for timepicker type Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME is not working in codename one

Tags: format, codenameone, timepicker

i am using time picker and date picker in my code. i am setting the format for date picker using setFormatter method it's working fine but while setting the format for time picker it's not taking the given format and it shows Illegal Argument Exception while running my code.it shows 24 hours format while opening time after click on set it shows 12 hours format. but i need while opening the time picker dialog it shows 12 hours format only.anything is wrong in my code.

Here is my code,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
datePicker = new Picker();
datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
datePicker.setFormatter(dateFormatter);
SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
timePicker = new Picker();
timePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
timePicker.setShowMeridiem(Boolean.TRUE);
timePicker.setFormatter(timeFormatter);
Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
c.add(datePicker);
c.add(timePicker);
dialogtimeForm.add(c);
```

please find the below image

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Time picker doesn't work with a `Date` object, it works with an integer representing time from midnight since `Date` is pretty bad at representing the abstract timezone insensitive time concept.

So the formatter is ignored for all types that aren't date or date & time (which is different from date).

You can do any custom formatting you want to the value by overwriting `updateValue` in the `Picker` class & calling `setText(String)` with the formatted value.

Comment: i have added the image link .please find the image, it shows 24 hours format only after selecting time it shows 12 hours format. But i want to display dialog with 12 hours format only.is it possible?

Comment: There is no screenshot, you don't set the value in the code which might impact this

Comment: " https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyTQj.png "   please open this link and check the time picker dialog shows 24 hours format.

Comment: That's the native device popup. It uses the OS native setting. You can change that in the system Settings app in iOS.

Comment: i done that setting.still it shows 24 hours format only

Comment: That's the OS behavior, we can't control that. If you want full control of a popup try using some of the other options suggested here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html